# Python pandas resaltar filas repetidas de un dataframe con doble header y exportarlo en excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un código en Python que maneja un dataframe con multiindex, el cuál es exportado a excel. Lo que quiero implementar dentro del código es alguna función que, en el excel, resalte las filas repetidas de la tabla.

Un ejemplo de resultado que quiero es el siguiete:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **C** | **D** |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Las filas que tienen 1,1 deben de ser resaltadas, ya que se repiten.

Aquí dejo lo que tengo del código, hasta el momento:

```
header=[['A', 'B'],
        ['C', 'D']]
 
merge2.columns=header

total_style = pd.Series("font-weight: bold;")
merge2.style.apply(lambda s: total_style)

path = r"test.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=merge2.droplevel([1], axis=1).columns)
df2 = merge2.droplevel(0, axis=1)

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', merge_cells = True, startrow=1)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Buen día, el código que muestras únicamente agrega la información al Excel, ¿Qué has intentado para agregar colores o formato a las celdas?

Comment: Buen día, intenté otros formatos de style que hacen eso pero ninguno funciona exitosamente.

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando la penúltima línea, la función se aplica de manera exitosa y guarda el formato automáticamente a excel.

```
df2['Duplicate'] = df2.duplicated()

df2.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: yellow' if (x.Duplicate == True) 
                          else ('background-color: white' if (x.Duplicate == False) else '') 
                          for i in x], axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', merge_cells = True, startrow=1)
```